# Как вывести в позицию курсора символ?

Tags: ассемблер, dos

Есть код

```
start:
mov ax,3
int 10h 
mov bh,0
xor ax,ax
int 33h
xchg ax,cx
jcxz exit
mov ax,0Ch
mov cx,10100b
push cs
pop es
mov dx,offset mouse 
int 33h
mov ax,1
int 33h

@@: mov ah,0
    int 16h
    dec ah
    jnz @b
        mov ax,14h
        xor cx,cx
        int 33h
exit:   int 20h

mouse proc far

    mov ax, cx ; cx = x
    shr ax, 3
    shr dx, 3 ;dx = y/8

    mov cx, ax ;cx = x/8

    mov ax, 0B800h
    mov es, ax

    mov ax, 80
    shl ax, 1
    mul dx
    shl cx, 1
    add ax, cx
    mov di, ax

    mov byte ptr es:[di], '1'

    retf
mouse endp

end start
```

При нажатии, символ появляется, но при движении снова исчезает.

Answer (score 1):

Если ваша программа применяет для вывода на экран метод прямой записи в видеопамять, перед обновлением содержимого экрана необходимо погасить курсор, а после завершения обновления - высветить его опять.

```
mouse proc far

    mov ax,2; Спрятать курсор
        int 33h

    mov ax, cx; ax <- x
    mov cl, 3
    shr ax, cl ; x : px -> #symbol
    shr dx, cl ; y : px -> #symbol

    mov dh, dl
    mov dl,al

    MOV  AH,02          
          MOV  BH,00          
          INT  10H

    MOV  AH,09          
          MOV  AL,1        
          MOV  BH,00          
          MOV  BL,0FH         
          MOV  CX,1          
          int 10H

     mov ax,1
        int 33h

    retf
mouse endp
```